# Example sites with broken security certs

Tags: security, ssl, https

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a demo site which shows different cases where HTTPS is misconfigured or broken. Or does anyone know of a website in the wild that deliberately displays various broken / misconfigured HTTPS cases? ... If not, how about ideas on how to track them down with a search engine? I'm looking for sites which exhibit broken https behaviors, for example:

- Self-signed certificate
- Certificatewith invalid subdomain
- Expired certificate
- Page with secure and un-secure content
- etc...

I'm looking to find a comprehensive list of the various ways that HTTPS can be misconfigured, and ideally perhaps live examples that I can use to hone a tool to crawl a page and tell you if it's going to produce any browser security errors. (As far as I know there is no such tool, short of a human operating a browser, anyone know of one?)

Comment: Interesting question. I disagree with the vote to close, such a resource would be useful.

Comment: One thing to note is that broken HTTPS behaviors may well be webserver specific - apache may not behave exactly the same as IIS may not behave the same as lighttpd, etc.

Comment: @Paul: or rather, browserspecific.

Comment: There are heaps of programs to test website security http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html . Maybe this question should be on serverfault instead.

Comment: @Thilo: you and paul are both right.

Comment: Why not just set up your own "server" and misconfigure it all you want?

Comment: @Chris -- do you know any resources on the various kinds of misconfigurations that are possible? The idea is that there is a common set that the major browsers provide error cases for, I'm want to zero in on what those error cases are or find a resource that describes them

Comment: @Robert -- Even reviewing that list I don't know of an SQA tool that can tell you if a site has misconfigured HTTPS. You're right, perhaps there is a sysadmin tool that can do the job

Comment: Just look at test sites such as Qualys' to see the latest broken SSL/TLS stuff

Comment: See https://badssl.com and its subdomains https://expired.badssl.com/ https://self-signed.badssl.com/  https://wrong.host.badssl.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Revisiting this. Here's a great online tool recently built: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/analyze.html

e.g.
Paypal:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/analyze.html?d=https://paypal.com

There are more details when you drill into a specific server.

When this question was asked I remember I was looking for resources I could use to build a tool that would automatically check if ssl was configured "properly" for a given site; at least that a given site was not going to display various ssl errors in various browsers. There are however many types of ssl/tls "misconfiguration" and many browsers handle the cases differently. Anticipating 100% if a browser is going to display any messaging at all or any given messaging about encryption is quite challenging as it turns out.

But this is a good manual tool. What would be great is an open source command line tool that has this level of summary, for plugging into deploy tests or monitoring.

Comment: For a command line tool similar to SSL Labs, check out https://testssl.sh/

Answer (score 3):

For those interested to know more about ssl under the covers, this page is very well worth a read http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html

Answer (score -1):

- https://mail.yahoo.com evidently is an example of a certificate with an invalid sub-domain. (Certificate for www.yahoo.com)
- https://verisign.com is another (Certificate for www.verisign.com)

-- Obviously any "in the wild" specimens are subject to change.

Comment: verisign auto forwards so it doesnt' really matter.

Comment: verisign: I get redirected to www.verisign.com immediately.

Comment: yahoo has been fixed now as well.

Comment: Maybe you pushed them to fix it :)

Comment: https://www.pcwebshop.co.uk/ - this is demo from https://onlinessl.netlock.hu/en/test-center/self-signed-ssl-certificate.html

Answer (score -1):

These may change but they currently reflect various certificate problems:

Intermediate certificate not installed:
http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=secure.donauversicherung.at

Exact hostname not in certificate:
http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=1stsource.com

Expired certificate:
http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=secure.garthbrooks.com

Self-signed certificate:
http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=www.mjvmobile.com.br

Certificate with an MD5 signature:
http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=www.mtsindia.in

Comment: All of the linked websites appear to be fixed, so they no longer make good examples.